# Terminology for a foliation that is only tangentially smooth

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, terminology, foliations, hyperbolic-dynamics

I'd like to get some information and references, starting with a name, for the following quite common situation, for a smooth (i.e. $C^\infty$) $n$-manifold $M$.  A partition $\mathcal{L}$ of $M$ is given such that
for any $p\in M$ there is an open nbd $U$ of $p$ and a homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^k\times  \mathbb{R}^{n-k}\to U$ such that

- $\big\{L\cap U: L\in\mathcal{L}\big\} = \big\{\phi(\mathbb{R}^k\times\{y\}):y\in  \mathbb{R}^{n-k}\big\}$
- For all $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k)\in\mathbb{N}^k$, the map $\phi$ has partial derivatives $\partial^\alpha\phi$, which are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^k\times  \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$.
- For all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^k\times  \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ the partial differential $D_1\phi(x,y)$ of $\phi$ (w.r.to its first variable $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$) is injective.

  In other words, $M$ is partitioned into smooth embedded $k$-submanifolds varying continuously (in the sense of the $C^\infty$ topology in the space of smooth embeddings). If we asked $\phi$ to be a smooth diffeomorphism, that would be a smooth foliation of $M$, but here there is no differentiability in directions transverse to the leafs, so that, for instance, the local distance between two close leafs may be $\epsilon$ somewhere and $\sqrt\epsilon$ somewhere else.

Comment: In his 1967 paper "Differentiable dynamical systems", Smale says (p. 760) that the stable manifolds of an Anosov diffeomorphism form a "continuous foliation".